# usage of attr_accessor in a rails model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Excuse me for the noob question.I am a newbie to ruby and rails and Needed some help in Understanding the attr_accessor which I have come across in the code

```
  create_table "pets", force: :cascade do |t|
            t.string   "name"
            t.string   "colour"
            t.string   "owner_name"
            t.text     "identifying_characteristics"
            t.text     "special_instructions"
            t.datetime "created_at"
            t.datetime "updated_at"
            t.string   "email"
            t.string   "password"
          end
```

model

```
 class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pet_photos
  cattr_accessor :form_steps do
    %w(identity characteristics instructions)
  end

  attr_accessor :form_step
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :name, :owner_name, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:identity) }
  validates :identifying_characteristics, :colour, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:characteristics) }
  validates :special_instructions, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:instructions) }

  def required_for_step?(step)
    return true if form_step.nil?
    return true if self.form_steps.index(step.to_s) <= self.form_steps.index(form_step)
  end



end
```

and

```
      class Pet::StepsController < ApplicationController
        include Wicked::Wizard
        steps *Pet.form_steps

        def show
          @pet = Pet.find(params[:pet_id])
          render_wizard
        end

        def update
          @pet = Pet.find(params[:pet_id])
          @pet.update(pet_params(step))

            if params[:images]

                params[:images].each do |image|
                @pet.pet_photos.create(image: image)
              end
            end

          render_wizard @pet
        end

        private

        def pet_params(step)
          permitted_attributes = case step
                                 when "identity"
                                   [:name, :owner_name]
                                 when "characteristics"
                                   [:colour, :identifying_characteristics]
                                 when "instructions"
                                   [:special_instructions]
                                 end

          params.require(:pet).permit(permitted_attributes).merge(form_step: step)
        end

      end
```

routes

```
  PetThing::Application.routes.draw do
          resources :pets, only: [:new, :create, :index, :destroy] do
            resources :steps, only: [:show, :update], controller: 'pet/steps'
          end

          root to: 'pets#index'
```

**1)** what  I all only know about  `attr_accessor`  is, it nothing more than a getter/setter for an object.I do not have a `form_step` as an attribute of my Pet Model(pets table).But in the model, there is `attr_accessor :form_step`.How is getter/setter generated to `:form_step` ?

**2)** Is `:form_step` an object of Pet class?

I am not totally understanding the usage of `attr_accessor` method in Rails model class.

**3)** Kindly explain me a scenario where I must generate getter/setter for Model attributes (pets table attributes or fields)

eg: `attr_accessor :name`
      `attr_accessor :colour` ..etc

when do we use `attr_accessor` for model attributes or fields?

Answer (score 7):

Lets starts with OOPs, basically `class` is template which defines properties and behavior of its instances i.e. objects.

The rails model also a ruby class. Its properties are being defined by `attr_accessor` and behaviors are defined by `static and instance methods`.

Consider a class `with attr_accessor`

```
class Animal
      //defines animal properties
      attr_accessor :legs
      //defines animal behavior
      def talk
      end
end
```

and `without attr_accessor`

```
class Animal
      //defines animal properties
      //getter
      def legs
        @legs
      end
      //setter
      def legs=(value)
        @legs = value
      end

      //defines animal behavior
      def talk
      end
end
```

Both representations are exactly same. The `attr_accessor` automatically add getter and setter for us and makes the life of developer easier.

Lets answer you questions

1. Ruby `attr_accessor` automatically adds these for you as explained earlier.
2. `form_step` its a attribute of `Pet class` and can be accessed as `petObj.form_step`.
3. If table is associated/mapped with Model, then you don't have to define columns in tables as `attr_accessor`, Rails automatically takes care for you. If field or attribute not exists in table, then you need to manually define it as `attr_accessor` in `Model`.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the Rails' magic is that when you have a class Pet and a table pets, you get the accessors for all the columns in the table for free. It's as if you've declared `attr-accessor` for all of them, only you don't need to.

In your example, `#form_step` is not created in the table. But it is declared using `attr_accessor`. It works just like plain old ruby. This gives you a getter/setter (answer to your Q1).

It's an instance method of Pet class. You call it on a Pet object, like `Pet.new.form_step = 5`(answer to Q2).

But you can't persist whatever value you assign to `#form_step` to db. So the answer to Q3 is that you usually do this when you need to pass some messages (i.e. call methods) between your objects, but you don't need to persist them to db.